# How do i run SQL function QUERY

Tags: sql, oracle, function

I have 4 tables

- `EMPLOYEE` (`E#, NAME`), primary key is `E#`
- `DRIVER` (`E#, L#`), primary key is `E#` references `EMPLOYEE`
- `TRIP` (`T#, L#`), primary key is `T#`, foreign key `L#` references `DRIVER`
- `TRIPPT` (`T#, PT#`) primary key is `T#` references `TRIP`

I have create a function that finds the length (total number of pt#) of the longest point perform by the driver

My query so far:

```
create or replace function LONGPT (DL# in TRIP.L#%type)
   return TRIPPT.PT#%type
IS
   TRIPPT#   TRIPPT.PT#%type;
begin
   select max (PT#)
     into TRIPPT# 
     from TRIPPT
    where T# in (select T#
                   from TRIP
                  where L# = DL#);

   return nvl (TRIPPT#, 0);
end LONGPT;
```

How can I do a select query to display the `NAME` of the employee, LONGPT. The driver name that perform no trip point need to be in the query as well.

I have tried:

```
SELECT DRIVER.L# AS License_No, LONGTPT(TRIP.L#) AS "LONGEST POINT" 
FROM DRIVER 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN TRIP on DRIVER.L# = TRIP.L#;
```

This only query the L# and the LONGEST Point.

Could anyone guide me how to do the select statement on display the NAME of the employee and  with my function LONGPT.

Comment: Yes it is Oracle. Sorry i'm new here not sure which to tag.

Comment: @letian It would be better to remove `#` from your column and table names.

Comment: the table is created by previous user with # i do not want to change the column name as it will messy up other query.

Comment: Here is the working query i manage to figure out. 

SELECT DISTINCT EMPLOYEE.NAME, LONGPT(TRIP.L#) AS "LONGEST Point" 
FROM DRIVER Join EMPLOYEE ON DRIVER.E# = EMPLOYEE.E# 
LEFT OUTER JOIN TRIP on DRIVER.L# = TRIP.L#;

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working query i manage to figure out.

```
SELECT DISTINCT EMPLOYEE.NAME, LONGPT(TRIP.L#) AS "LONGEST Point"
FROM DRIVER Join EMPLOYEE ON DRIVER.E# = EMPLOYEE.E# LEFT OUTER JOIN 
TRIP on DRIVER.L# = TRIP.L#;
```